# Button not shown in Android layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to create the layout with a `EditText`,`TextView` and two `Buttons`.

Here is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25sp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command.."
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="20" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bResults"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="Try Command" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:paddingBottom="10sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason the two buttons are not shown up on the layout? Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: remove android:weightSum="20"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Try Command" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `weighsum` is 20 but you set the weight 50 and 80. you better remove the `android:weightsum` attribute

Comment: ohh darn! sorry dont know how i overlooked it.THanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25sp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command.."
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bResults"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Try Command" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:paddingBottom="10sp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the weight in your horizontal linearlayout, use smaller values​​, like 1 and 2.

android:layout_weight="80"
android:layout_weight="50"

Try this and you can check that you can see the two button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25sp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command.."
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="20" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bResults"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Try Command" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```